# Separated compilation with multiple sources by Makefile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a simple Makefile to compile several type of sources. And it works well. This Makefile will find all the `protobuf` sources and `C++` sources. So making the program will act as follow.

1. `protoc` will generate `C++` sources files with `*.proto`
2. `g++` will compile object files with `*.cpp` and `*.pb.cc` (generated by step 1)
3. `g++` (actually is `ld`) will link all the object `*.obj` to a **single** executable

This Makefile sample is:

```
# Define the protoc generator
PROTOC = protoc
INCLUDE = -I$(SOMEPLACE) 
LIB = -lxml2  -lpthread -lz

# The final single outputted executable
OUTPUT  = svrkit_adapter_v2

# Define the cpp source code/object result
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

# Define the proto's source/generated result/object result
PROTO_SOURCES = $(wildcard *.proto)
PROTO_CPPSRC = $(patsubst %.proto,%.pb.cc,$(PROTO_SOURCES))
PROTO_OBJECT = $(patsubst %.proto,%.pb.o,$(PROTO_SOURCES))

# First actual making target
all:$(OUTPUT) 

# Define the rule for generating proto's cpp sources
$(PROTO_CPPSRC) : $(PROTO_SOURCES)
  $(PROTOC) --cpp_out=. $(filter %.proto, $^) 

# Define the rule for compiling generated proto cpp sources
$(PROTO_OBJECT) : $(PROTO_CPPSRC)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $(filter %.cc, $^) 

# Define the rule for compiling other cpp sources
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) $(PROTO_OBJECT)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $(filter %.cpp, $^) 

# Define the rule for linking the final executable
$(OUTPUT): $(OBJECTS) $(PROTO_OBJECT)
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ ${LIB}

clean:
  rm -f *.o *.~ *.bak *.pb.*
  rm -f $(OUTPUT)
```

However the command lines executed by make are as follow (for example):

```
protoc a.proto b.proto
g++ -c a.pb.cc b.pb.cc
g++ -c x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp
g++ -o output a.o b.o x.o y.o z.o
```

Sometime it works well. **But if the sources are too many, it will cost a lot of time to recompile some unchanged sources.** For example, I just modified `a.proto` and the Makefile will also recompile `b.proto`.

My question is: how can I make each source file be compiled/generated **separately**. The executed command lines should be:

```
protoc a.proto
protoc b.proto
g++ -c a.pb.cc -o a.o
g++ -c b.pb.cc -o b.o
g++ -c x.cpp -o x.o
g++ -c y.cpp -o y.o
g++ -c z.cpp -o z.o
g++ -o output a.o b.o x.o y.o z.o
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make the mistake of having rules working on complete lists instead of individual files, taking away `make`'s ability to *work* on individual files.

Your generation rules:

```
# Define the rule for generating proto's cpp sources
$(PROTO_CPPSRC) : $(PROTO_SOURCES)
  $(PROTOC) --cpp_out=. $(filter %.proto, $^) 

# Define the rule for compiling generated proto cpp sources
$(PROTO_OBJECT) : $(PROTO_CPPSRC)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $(filter %.cc, $^)
```

Instead, make the rules work on *individual files*.

```
# Define the rule for generating proto's cpp sources
%.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) --cpp_out=. $<       

# Define the rule for compiling generated proto cpp sources
%.pb.o: %.pb.cc
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@
```

The same goes for your C++ sources:

```
# Define the rule for compiling other cpp sources
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) $(PROTO_OBJECT)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $(filter %.cpp, $^)
```

(Why is `$(PROTO_OBJECT)` included in the dependencies? This looks *very* wrong to me.)

Again, switch this to work on individual files instead of whole lists:

```
# Define the rule for compiling other cpp sources
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@
```

Only the final target needs the full list of objects:

```
# Define the rule for linking the final executable
$(OUTPUT): $(OBJECTS) $(PROTO_OBJECT)
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ ${LIB}
```

Drop `PROTO_CPPSRC`, it is not needed.

Now, `make` will look at that last rule, find the object dependencies, and will apply the *single-file* rule on each object that needs rebuilding.

---

Unrelated to your question, but while you're at it, add the following statement to your Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

This will make "all" and "clean" to run *always*, *even if a file with that name exists*. This is not often a problem, but when it happens, it can be confusing as heck. ;-)

Comment: The first upvote to this question made my C++ gold badge. I'm fangirling all over it right now. ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much. Putting `$(PROTO_OBJECT)` in the dependency list makes sure `*.pb.h` can be generated before compiling other normal cpp sources. Otherwise, it will course `xx.pb.h` not found error.

Comment: @AlexanderChen: Ah... you didn't mention any `*.pb.h` before. Is it a side-effect of `$(PROTOC)` running? In that case, you need to make sure that running it over the `*.proto` sources one file at a time instead of the full list does not break anything. Some generators can be brain-dead that way, and it would defeat your efforts to come up with a minimal run. Perhaps you could be more explicit, and have a rule with `*.pb.h` as a target depending on `$(PROTO_OBJECT)`, and having `$(OBJECTS)` depend on `*.pb.h`. (Easier to read / maintain.)

Comment: You mean to add a rule `%.o: %.cpp %.pb.h`. That's incorrect. Because the object `x.o` is compiled from `x.cpp`, which depends on `a.pb.h` (perhaps `b.pb.h` is also needed) instead of `x.pb.h`. So all the normal sources **MUST** be compiled after **ALL** the protobuf sources have been generated correctly. So my solution is add dependency rule `%.o: %.cpp $(PROTO_OBJECT)` to ensure all headers required by `$.cpp` are updated. On the other hand, rule `%.o: %.cpp $(PROTO_CPPSRC)` is also a correct option, but after making the intermediate files `*.pb.cpp` will be deleted.

Comment: @AlexanderChen: Without knowing what *exactly* your $(PROTOC) step does, and how your files are interdependent with each other, I'm the one-legged in an arse-kicking contest here. I just suggest that Makefiles should follow the rule "say what you mean, mean what you say" -- your objects do not depend on `$(PROTO_OBJECT)`, and neither do they depend on `$(PROTO_CPPSRC)`, they depend on header files. If at all possible, your Makefile should reflect that. (If it is *not* possible, as your last comment seems to indicate, too bad.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the whole answer to your question but I think it could help
you.  Here is an example of the makefile I use :

```
EXEC=prog1
EXEC+=prog2

prog1_SRCS=prog1.cpp source1.cpp source2.cpp
prog2_SRCS=prog2.cpp source3.cpp

#------------------------------------------------------------------
#no need to change anything below that line (maybe add some OPTION)

CXX = g++ -std=c++11

ERRORS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
OPTION = 

BUILD=build

CXXFLAGS = $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)
LDFLAGS  = $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)

SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)

all: OPTION += -O3 -DNDEBUG
all:$(EXEC)

debug: OPTION += -ggdb 
debug:$(EXEC)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXEC): $$(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD)/%.o, $$($$@_SRCS)) 
    @echo Links $(notdir $^)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) 

$(BUILD)/%.o:%.cpp
    @echo Creates $(notdir $@)
    $(CXX) -MD -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

-include $(addprefix $(BUILD)/,$(SRCS:.cpp=.d))

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD)/* $(EXEC)
```

you'll need a directory called `build` to save `.o` and `.d` file. they will
allow you to recompile only the files that have been modified